# how to get tables, views, etc.. in mysql database server from a firebird database server

Tags: mysql, database, firebird

There are two different database servers in different platforms; MySql and Firebird. 
I need to get db tables from Firebird server (synchronously or not synchronously) to MySql server. 
Timing is not that important. 
How do I achieve to get, for example; simply a specific database table from Firebird server to Mysql server?

İt will be very helpful if any ideas come, thank you..

Comment: You develop code around this problem. You cant take a table from MySQL and put it in firebird just like that. It is called a ETL process.

Comment: Well, a table from Firebird db; firstly going to be EXTRACT, and TRANSFORM and then LOAD into MySQL db, i guess.. Besides (i know it is not simple but) this ETL process needs coding you say.. In which step do i need to code or are there any example about this?

Comment: Are you going to be using .Net or Java or which language? This is a very open ended question.

Comment: Here in ETL process i think i need only MySQL script language. Because i'm going to extract datas (tables, .. etc) from firebird database, and load into mysql database. I'm a php user by the way.

Comment: i saw kind of similar example in this link: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/databases/2007/04/12/building-a-data-warehouse-with-mysql-and-perl.html?page=2 . But in the link, it takes data from CSV file. i need to extract it from firebird.

Comment: develop a php script that connect to firebird select the needed data and dump into mysql. You wont be able to do this in MySQL natively.

Comment: So then this is not going to be etl process, is it?

Comment: I'm asking this cause i have  presentation tomorrow

Comment: You can create csv from within the Firebird using its feature of raw binary files i/o, see EXTERNAL TABLE. But doing this by PSQL script is probably rather tedious task. Also I think you'd have to add into the table a replication flag (if reuse the Auto Inc I'd if there is to know like all rows I'd <= 12345 were already replicated, If the rows are immutable after stored once)

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you would need to develop some sort of process that will extract then transform and load the data from FireBird into MySQL. The problem is that both firebird and MySQL does not have real ETL tools included in them by default. MSSQL has for example SSIS. Since you cant access FireBird directly from MySQL code you will need some external tool to do the job.

Thus you will either have to code this tool yourself or use a open source tool.

There are several ETL tools that are open source and for free that you might want to investigate such as Pentaho, CloverETL see [this link](http://www.etltool.com/open-source-etl-tools/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You told you already found a solution to import CSV into MySQL. So the missing piece is *Firebird CSV export*

Well,  those three words entered into Google give you immediate top result as the free **FBExport** tool. See http://www.firebirdfaq.org/fbexport.php